# Wold Decomposition -- summation to infinity

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, notation, moving-average, decomposition

In Wold's decomposition we have $ Y_t = \sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j \varepsilon_{t-j} + \eta_t $, where the variables have definition as in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem).

I'm confused about why the summation goes to infinity. What does this equation mean when $j > t$?

I think what the equation is trying to say is that the summation actually goes to $t$, but that we do this for all our $t$s (at least, that's what I gather from the answer to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324134/difference-between-the-wold-decomposition-and-ma-representation) question, where the summation of $j$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$). Would it be correct to interpret the decomposition this way? If so, then the decomposition can be thought of as

$ Y_t = \sum_{j=0}^t b_j \varepsilon_{t-j} + \eta_t$

but where we work this same equation through all our $T \in \left(0,1,...,t \right)$.

Is that right, or is there something I'm missing? Thank you.

Comment: If you consider what it means for $Y_t$ to be second-order stationary, you can deduce what the $\varepsilon_{t-j}$ must be for $j\gt t.$

Comment: Thanks as always whuber. I see it more clearly now. I was getting tripped up in the transition from the general form to actual implementation.